# How to install MySQL 5.7.23 on Mac via Brew

Tags: mysql, macos, installation, homebrew

I'm unable to install the specific sub version 5.7.23 on mac, however I'm able to install just MySQL 5.7, which is something i don't want. Any ideas? I'm using macOS10.15.4

```
brew install mysql@5.7.23
Error: No available formula with the name "mysql@5.7.23"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: There’s no supported way to do that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53766019/735926.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to homebrew-core versioned formulae [support policy](https://docs.brew.sh/Versions):

> Versioned formulae should differ in major/minor (not patch) versions from the current stable release. This is because patch versions indicate bug or security updates, and we want to ensure you apply security updates.

The latest `mysql@5.7` points to `mysql@5.7 5.7.31`. [GitHub PR reference](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/58147)

You should be able to use the latest 5.7.x series with `brew install mysql@5.7` or `brew upgrade mysql@5.7` (if you already installed it).

Comment: Not working; I get the same error with `mysql@5.7`.